# Retrieve positions of unique characters in character string in R

Tags: r, string, character, uniqueidentifier

I'm trying to track sampling effort for pollen counts.  My group is trying to see how many different pollen species we count compared to total number of grains counted.  These are similar to rarefaction and species accumulation curves, but these r packages are too complex for the simplified outputs our group desires.

I have a keyboard-based tally counter program that allows me to assign pollen species unique alpha numeric case sensitive characters and type these into a text editor. Then the program converts this character string into a csv file with the pollen species and counts of each species in the sample.

Since this program uses a character string, I would like the ability to identify the location of the unique characters in the character string.  This would yield a vector of positions for the first appearance of a unique character.  Example:

character string `"1bd3db12"` would yield output:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 8
```

I looked into regex and extract functions, but I can't find one that will identify the positions of the first unique character in a string.  Automating this process would save my group a great deal of time since we sometimes end up with 500-600 grain pollen counts composed of 30-40 species.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split it into characters, look for which characters are non-duplicated

```
s="1bd3db12"
which(!duplicated(strsplit(s,"")[[1]]))
[1] 1 2 3 4 8
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for in a simple clean code.  I knew I was overlooking something simple, but for some reason I couldn't bring it to the top of my head or think of a good way to search for it.  Now I it's time foe me to begin coding it for graphs.  That I can handle.  Thanks for the quick assist.